# Actionscript 3 re-arrange URL?

Tags: string, url, flickr, actionscript-3

How can I get this URL:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.auth.getFrob&format=rest&api_key=xxx&perms=write&api_sig=xxx
```

Into:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/auth/?api_key=xxx&perms=write&frob=xxx&api_sig=xxx
```

The frob parameter I have extracted from XML and stored in a string, so it looks like

```
String frob;
String originalURL;
//just need to join frob as well remove and rearrange accordingly
```

Comment: Do I understand correct-You need to get part of first address starting from `api_key` and add it to `http://api.flickr.com/services/auth/?`? Why not use `indexOf` to find index of `api_key` and then use substring?

Comment: yes but also I have to include the 'frob=' parameter after the 'perms=' in the new string would I use the same method for that aswell ?? Forgot to mention its in string format all of the variables, but you probably already knew that

Comment: From what I know You can add `frob` at the end of Your URL, this will be the same request :)

Comment: Thats right thx!! feeling very stupid right now lol

Comment: No problem :) I've posted a sample answer to show You some code. If its OK please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var orgURL:String="http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.auth.getFrob&format=rest&api_key=xxx&perms=write&api_sig=xxx";
var index:int = orgURL.indexOf("api_key");
var newURL:String="http://api.flickr.com/services/auth/?"+orgURL.substr(index)+"&frob=xxx";
```

or even simpler:

```
var orgURL:String="http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.auth.getFrob&format=rest&api_key=xxx&perms=write&api_sig=xxx";
var newURL:String="http://api.flickr.com/services/auth/?"+orgURL.substr(orgURL.indexOf("api_key"))+"&frob=xxx";
```

Probably there is a method of doing this with regex, but this one is easier to understand :)